# Woocommerce Rest API. Checksum error while uploading WebP file from another server

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am sending a post request to woocommerce REST API to create a product with an image on it (https://cdn.beymen.com/productimages/opfgmmmg.0cz_IMG_01_2110085666379.jpg) (the extension of the file in the url is `jpg` but when you download it you can see that it is actually `webP` file).

When I upload another webP images that actually ends with `webp` it is working. but when I am uploading the url above I am gettin this error.

`{'code': 'woocommerce_product_image_upload_error', 'message': 'Ошибка дистанционного получения изображения https://cdn.beymen.com/productimages/opfgmmmg.0cz_IMG_01_2110085666379.jpg. Ошибка: The checksum of the file (4572785d201f809bcdc2a9b7bf82e305) does not match the expected checksum value (feb886e9d82201b5189e121da761451d).', 'data': {'status': 400}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using the following snippet

```
add_filter('wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', 'real_image_ext');

function real_image_ext($file){
    $real_mime = wp_get_image_mime( $file['tmp_name'] );
    $mime_to_ext = apply_filters(
        'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts',
        array(
            'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
            'image/png'  => 'png',
            'image/gif'  => 'gif',
            'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
            'image/tiff' => 'tif',
            'image/webp' => 'webp',
        )
    );
    if ( ! empty( $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ] ) ) {
        $file['name'] = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.' . $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ];
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, which file should I add it? I am new to WP

Comment: Add it to functions.php of your active theme (preferably a child-theme)